# Find the volume of the intersection of the regions $x^2+y^2\leq R^2$ and $x^2+z^2\leq R^2$ for any $R>0$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm not sure if I use spherical coordinates for this question

Comment: And here's the answer for a more general situation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338708/volume-of-the-intersection-of-two-cylinders

Answer (score 1):

Look at this picture:

[image]

The projection onto $yz$ plane is a square. So, is the use of polar coordinates a proper method?