# Let S be the intersection of two cylinders or radius r whose axis intersect at angle theta, find the volume...

Tags: calculus, volume

I have this problem and I understand most of it, but am having trouble deriving the formula for the side of each rhombus. I think I just can't visualize it well. Can anyone draw a picture that would help me find the side length of the rhombus?

"Let S be the intersection of two cylinders with radius r that intersect at angle theta. Find the volume of S as a function of r and theta.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa05F.png)

Comment: Why don't you draw it on [Geogebra online](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry)?

Comment: Please show your work. Draw a picture of  two sets two parallel lines of same normal distance = diameter = 2r to get that rhombus.

Comment: Even though this post is closed, this comment is to link this post as one of the [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868) to the current choice of [mother/target post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338708).

Answer (score 1):

Consider one of the cylinders, and take a plane parallel to its axis and at distance $0 \le d \le r$ from it.
The intersection of the plane with the cylinder will be two parallel lines,  which will be at distance $2\sqrt{r^2-d^2}$ from each other. Can you visualize that ?

Then given two cylinders, whose axes intersect, the two axes will lay on a plane which cuts each cylinder in half. Any plane parallel to that and at distance $d$ from it, will cut each cylinder in a couple of lines as said before.

Those two couples of lines, inclined by the angle $\theta$ are making the rhombus.